# Using types instead for basic proofs

Tags: notation, type-theory

*Disclaimer*: I know close to nothing about formal type theory, but I program intensively so prefer to think in terms of types.

In typical math you write $a \in A$ to speak of the nature of your objects or elements. However, I prefer to think instead of types and list, which is more common in computer science.

I would like to write something like

$$a  : A $$
$$l  : List \hspace{1 mm}A$$
$$a  \in l$$

While I would be able to understand myself, I want to make sure other also understand me, what notation can I use?

Comment: I think anyone familiar with type theory would understand something like $l \in \textrm{List} \: A$.

Comment: The nice thing about types is that, as in the example I gave, you get a syntactic separation of the definition of the structure of the objects, and their belonging to a certain collection. With set, its all belonging, the structure is infered.

Comment: I guess so. For example, if $l ∈ \textrm{List} \: A$ it wouldn't even make sense to ask if $x ∈ l$ because $l$ can't be a type, but in set theory it's always possible to ask that, and there might actually exist such $x$. But I also like to view type inference as a simple decision procedure for set membership. And set membership can also apply to function types. For example, $+ ∈ ℕ → ℕ → ℕ$.

Comment: I don't know if I am using the wrong notation but I understand that `a : A` reads as `a` is of type `A`. So I am saying that `l` is of type `List A` and that `a` belongs to the list `l`.

Comment: @ChristianGarcia Are you trying to consider membership as a relations in the proposition as type paradigm?